# using case statement in bash to pass in only arguments

Tags: bash

I have the following code in my script:

```
case "$1" in
    (-h)
            display_help
            exit 0
            ;;
    (start)
            start_services
            ;;
    (stop)
            stop_services
            ;;
    (*)
            display_help
            exit 0
            ;;
esac
```

I want to be able to pass in an argument when one of these commands is called.  For example, I want to start only a users service.  I would issue the following command:

```
./services.sh start users
```

If I just enter:

```
./services.sh start
```

That works as expected, all services are started.  However, if I issue the command with a service attached to it, like described above, it still starts all services, not just that service.  The code in the start_services() function looks for an argument to start that service.

How do I get it so that it only starts that one service within the case statement?

Comment: You should consider using `getotpts()` for this

Answer (score 3):

If `start_services` *looks for an argument*, you have to pass it:

```
start_services "$2"
```

Comment: Or, more generically: `(start) shift; start_services "$@" ;;`